# oauth_token and oauth_token_secret in a jwt

Tags: twitter, oauth, jwt, jwe

quick question - using twitter's oauth, I'm given an oauth_token and oauth_token_secret to validate users.

I know I can store this encrpyted in a database for safekeeping, but is it a bad idea to simply sick them in an encrpted jwt (jwe)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Secret should be kept secret.

You will use the token to make api calls on behalf of the user. Keeping this in mind, it's ok to store the token in a jwt (but probably not the best practice), but definitely not ok to store the secret.

A possibly better pattern would be to store the token and secret in your user's model and refer to that user by storing the user's id in your jwt. Since you'll be sending the jwt with every request, you can decode the jwt, get the user's id and look up the user's model and make calls from there.

Comment: But then I need to store the secret in a data base then?  The user model has to be persisted somewhere right?

Comment: Yes. When I say user model, I'm referring to your db user model.